# Insert.. select.. case - is there any way to get 2 columns?

Tags: t-sql, insert, case

a have a table and i want to insert something to this table (very original of me ;P).

so i have:

```
INSERT into TARGET_TABLE ([...], tcol1, tcol2)
SELECT [...],
        (SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN smth IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT Q_COL1 [...]
                WHEN smthelse IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT Q_COL1 [from the same table but via different fk and through another tables]
        END)
FROM another_table
```

and it works fine.

BUT

i need another value from just another table which is strictly connected to the Q_COL1 and it can be easy obtained using one simple JOIN in SELECT Q_COL1 part.

But the (SELECT CASE ...) should return one value only.

Ofc i can do another round and just add another Insert but i don't like it -i'd rather do this once, with one insert.

Any clues? :)

EDIT:
I figured it out!

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE([...], tcol1, tcol2)
SELECT .... COALESCE(t1c1.val1, t2c1.val1), COALESCE(t1c2.val2, t2c2.val2)
FROM another_table
JOIN table_in_between1..
JOIN table_in_between2..
JOIN table_for_col1 t1c1 ON t1c1.Id=table_in_between1.idt1c1
JOIN table_for_col1 t2c1 ON t2c1.Id=table_in_between2.idt2c1
JOIN table_for_col2 t1c2 ON t1c2.Id = t1c1.id..
JOIN table_for_col2 t2c2 ON t2c2.Id = t2c1.Id...
```

In addition the execution plan is much better now (without stream aggregates and eager spools).

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should add your solution as an answer and select it as the correct one. That way others can see you've already obtained an answer and it'll be clearer to anyone that arrives at your question seeking a similar solution.

Comment: gladly, but unfortunatelly the message says "you can accept your own answer in 2 days" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE([...], tcol1, tcol2)
SELECT .... COALESCE(t1c1.val1, t2c1.val1), COALESCE(t1c2.val2, t2c2.val2)
FROM another_table
JOIN table_in_between1..
JOIN table_in_between2..
JOIN table_for_col1 t1c1 ON t1c1.Id=table_in_between1.idt1c1
JOIN table_for_col1 t2c1 ON t2c1.Id=table_in_between2.idt2c1
JOIN table_for_col2 t1c2 ON t1c2.Id = t1c1.id..
JOIN table_for_col2 t2c2 ON t2c2.Id = t2c1.Id...
```

In addition the execution plan is much better now (without stream aggregates and eager spools).